# Alfresco fails to handle file upload

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, alfresco

When i try to upload a file in alfresco i get the below error.

```
type Exception report

message 

description `The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

exception 

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/alfresco/webservice/util/AuthenticationUtils
    com.corelogic.sample.upload.doPost(upload.java:171)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 logs.
```

please can anyone tell me whats wrong

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an alfresco library. Make sure your installation is complete.